# Sharing collections with spring singleton beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, singleton, javabeans

I want to save a list of pairs of users in Spring MVC application. The list can be accessed and changed by any user (pairs can be deleted, new ones can be added). I don't want to save this list as a table in a database, since I expect a lot of pairs of users be formed during the execution of the web app, and this procedure should be performed frequently. I decided this list to be a field of a Singleton Spring bean (named ListHolder for example), which is wired to different controllers. Because of the fact that I am new in Spring, my concern is a possible race condition that may occur when a lot of users will be using the app at the same time. How can I protect my List from such kind of situations? Is it the correct way of saving data in spring app? What are the best practices?

P.S. When I want to add a pair I just user List.add method. while deleting, I first copy the whole List, then iterate through it (copy), delete the needed ones, change the List reference.

Comment: Use a Concurrent Collection

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. It'll protect your list from multithreading.